# Cannot access a field from a static extending class contained in the same .java file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I cannot figure out if this is a hidden feature I have never discovered or a bug from IntelliJ Idea.

Having this class,

```
public class StackOverflow {
    private String abc;

    public static class StackOverflowExtended extends StackOverflow {
        public StackOverflowExtended() {
            abc = "";
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ tells me that I cannot access `abc` because either it has private access or because I'm in a static context.

As soon as I access `abc` by `super`, it starts working.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    private String abc;

    public static class StackOverflowExtended extends StackOverflow {
        public StackOverflowExtended() {
            super.abc = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second shouldn't work either, subclasses can access `private` fields of their parents.

Comment: @daniu Seems to work (atleast Eclipse doesn't complain), maybe because `StackOverflowExtended` is defined inside `StackOverflow`? If I place `StackOverflowExtended` outside it indeed says the field is not visible.

Comment: @daniu subclasses CANNOT* access private fields of their parents

Comment: @balsick of course, typo. Can't edit anymore :/

Comment: anyways IntelliJ says it's ok using super.abc to set the value, but javac of course says no

Comment: Actually i tried it with super and private abc, and it works for me :O

Comment: @aBnormaLz using what IDE? :O

Comment: It (private with super) works with `javac` on the command line.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException what version? I'm using javac 1.8.0_181

Comment: It works with Java 8 and 11. Here's a confirmation it works with 1.8.0_112: https://ideone.com/8CEyTu

Answer (score 2):

There's no bugs or hidden features going on. You're probably mixing up inheritance and inner classes.

A **non-static** inner class can access the variables of its outer class, even if they're private.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    private String abc;
    public class StackOverflowExtended extends StackOverflow {
        public StackOverflowExtended() {
            abc = "";
        }
    }
}
```

A static inner class cannot access the fields of its outer class, because it's static. It can exist without having an instance of its outer class.

The reason why `super.abc` works on the static inner class, is due to it being its subclass. Accessibility independent of its scope, is then again due to it being an inner class.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't work for me. IntelliJ Idea says it's ok, javac says it is not. I've tried additional tools like ideone and playground.java and it works on their machines. On my javac 1.8.0_191 it does not and I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 1):

The scope and accessibility of any private member (field, constructor or method) is the complete body of its declaring class, including any nested classes.

If the inner class is non-static, it is bound to the instance of the outer class, so you can access the private instance variable.

In your case, the inner class is static, so you need to specify an object instance of the outer class, such as `super` (because in your case the inner class extends the outer class).

The only "weird" thing is that when you try to access it using `this.abc`, it fails because then apparently the rule that subclasses cannot access private members of their parents takes precedence.